# An attempt to understand Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, education

Can I learn quantum mechanics just by knowing basic calculus and algebra?

- I know basic differential calculus and integral calculus.
- I am willing to study to understand what quantum mechanics means.
- Moreover, I want to know the beauty it holds and learn one of the most sensational subjects of this century.

Comment: You can read Feynman book which uses less math.

Comment: I would say it depends on the approach as well. Some books I have seen start with a wave formulation more and that needs some differential equation knowledge. Another book I have used, Townsend's Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics, uses very simple math and I think would absolutely be learnable with the effort.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Quantum physics is very accessible, and with basic knowledge of calculus you can learn.

Comment: can i chat with you, like right now..?

Comment: sure (more characters)

Comment: Is there a website where we could talk like facebook or any mail sites.??

Comment: tell me when you've seen that so i can take it down

Comment: I have seen it.

Comment: @Zarkaan: you know that there is a physics chat right on this site? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar

Comment: Oh yea... I'm new to this site.

Comment: I think his reputation is too low to use the general chat.

Comment: yea i guess..... i can talk on mail. Thanks alot for this oppurtunity.

Comment: I have sent you a mail. @Jimmy360

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are looking for the "big picture" of quantum mechanics, not the ability to do extensive calculations.  For this, in my opinion, you should start by understanding observables with two possible values (like spin in a particular direction, which is either up or down), rather than observables with infinitely many possible values (like position or momentum).  Once you understand the simpler case, you'll understand all the key "big picture" ideas for the more difficult case.

For this, the key mathematical tool that you still need to acquire is linear algebra.  Take a good linear algebra course --- mastering concepts like "vector space", "basis", "linear transformation", "change of basis", "eigenvalue" and "eigenvector" -- and you'll be able to pick up the big picture of quantum mechanics in an afternoon.